# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de verificar el tiempo transcurrido de una columna datetime?

Tags: c#, sql-server

estoy desarrollando un sistema de alertas en el cual doy la opción de que se pueda hacer una escalación de las alertas (Básicamente que a los X minutos se envíe un mensaje mediante telegram), los registros tienen una columna del tipo datetime la cual es la que necesito comprobar si es mayor a los X minutos que especifica el usuario.

Actualmente esta comprobación la hago mediante un método en C#, pero siento que no es ni de cercas la mejor forma de hacerlo, creo que se puede realizar esta comprobación desde sql server, pero no sé por donde empezar, estoy abierto a cualquier idea que puedan dar.

Gracias de antemano.

```
while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                using (EntityContext DB = new EntityContext())
                {
                    var calls = DB.CALL.ToList().Where(x => x.Call_Type == "call" && x.Scaled == false);
                    if (calls != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var call in calls)
                        {
                            var REQ = DB.REQ_BUTTON.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key_Button == call.Key_Pressed && x.Req_Code == call.Req_Code);
                            if (REQ != null)
                            {
                                TimeSpan transcurrido = System.DateTime.Now - call.Call_Time;
                                double minutos = transcurrido.TotalMinutes;
                                if (minutos >= REQ.Wait_Time)
                                {
                                    string Mensaje = "▸Línea: " + call.Req_Name + getMessageTelegram(call.Req_Code, call.Key_Pressed) + "%0A▸Fecha: " + call.Call_Time;
                                    telegramMethods.Get(REQ.ID_Telegram, Mensaje);
                                    call.Scaled = true;                                        
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        DB.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Creo que esta bien que lo hagas en C# en el backend, podrias usar la clase Timer, y una pregunta, el valor datetime de tu base de datos, cuando cambia?

Comment: Nunca cambia, supongamos que se hace un registro y el usuario tiene definido que a los 5 minutos se tiene que enviar el mensaje, entonces de alguna forma tengo que saber si el tiempo transcurrido de ese datetime es mayor a los 5 minutos, lo compruebo cada 1000ms, pero siento que es una mala práctica hacerlo así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes filtrar desde la base de datos, por ejemplo, para obtener los registros que tienen `Call_Time` hace diez o más minutos, podrías hacer:

```
var calls = DB.CALL.ToList().Where(x => x.Call_Type == "call" && 
                                        x.Scaled == false &&
                                        x.Call_Time <= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10)
                                   );
```

Esto aumenta la eficiencia de la aplicación, sobre todo si trabajas con volúmenes altos de datos, pues la base de datos puede valerse de índices para acceder a ellos, por mencionar uno de los mecanismos de optimización.